# How do I return a value from an AutoHotkey script?

Tags: return, autohotkey

I need to call an AutoHotkey script that will return a value.

For example, something like this:

```
return_val = Shell("AutoHotKey.exe script.ahk")
```

My script looks like this:

```
IfExists, filename
     return 1
Else
     return 0
```

I get an error telling me I can't have a value in the terminating return statement. I have also tried using the [Exit](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Exit.htm) statement instead of return.

How can I return a value from an AutoHotkey script?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To return an exit code you'll want to call [ExitApp](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ExitApp.htm) along with your desired code. Use [IfExist](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/IfExist.htm) to determine if the file exists. This means the script that you call should look like this:

```
IfExist, c:\test.txt
    ExitApp, 1
Else
    ExitApp 0
```

When calling the script you should use [RunWait](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Run.htm) and pass it the `UseErrorLevel` parameter. This will set the variable `ErrorLevel` to the exit code of the called process if it launches correctly or the text `ERROR` if the process cannot be started.

```
RunWait, C:\Program Files (x86)\AutoHotkey\AutoHotkey.exe "C:\script.ahk",, UseErrorLevel
MsgBox %ErrorLevel%
```

In this example the message box will display '1' if the file exists or '0' if it doesn't.